# Is it possible to change the default raster style of newly created rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, style

If I do calculations on rasters with the raster calculator or other tools, the resulting rasters displayed in my canvas are always in the same default style (singleband gray, black to white...) so that I have to change it afterwards to my preferred style. Being able to change that default raster style to my own choice would save me a lot of clicks.

@Joseph:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "C:/Users/Gumbo/.qgis2/python/plugins\multiqml\multiqml.py", line 98, in on_pbnApplyStyle_clicked
> >         self.myPluginMessage( QCoreApplication.translate("MultiQmlDlg", "Unable to apply vector qml style \"%1\" to raster layer \"%2\".")\
> >     AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'arg'

Comment: Why not save the style file with your preferred settings and load it when creating other rasters?

Comment: Sounds good, but could you be a little more specific? What is the style file / Where can I find it? And how to load it when using the raster calculator to create a new raster?

Comment: Huh, it seems like it may be a bug. I tried going into _Layer Properties_ > _Save Style..._ and loading it again but still get the default. Have you tried downloading the **multiQML** plugin and applying the style through that?

Comment: Ah ok now I see what the Style file is. That is maybe a little quicker but I still have to go into the Properties and then browse to the file. MultiQML seems interesting but I get an error whenever I load a Style file, which I copied into the initial post. It says it can't apply vector style file to a raster layer, but I saved the style file directly from the properties tab of a raster layer...

Comment: I also had a very similar (if not the exact same) error for the **multiQML** plugin. I managed to resolve it by reinstalling it.

Comment: Very strange, indeed I can apply the style file (extracted from a raster layer) on a Vector layer...that now seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Just to finish this, I didn't get multiQML to work, but I found that you can also just right click on raster layers, _copy style_, right click the next layer and _paste style_

Comment: That's a nice, easy alternative (I _right-click_ layers all the time and I still missed that!). Glad you found something to work.